# Scroll on top onclick href id?

Tags: javascript, scroll, href

I have this problem:

```
<a href="http://google.com" name="iframe" id="test">Google</a>
```

The page use this javascript: pastebin.com/DGN7CM9v

I need that on click it scroll to top, how I can do?

I already tried to read in this forum and in Google but nothing, I also use wordpress. What can I do? Online I find only how to scroll link without link.

Regards

Comment: Are you trying to click a link and expecting the page to scroll to the top?

Comment: Yes, I just now try ( onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 0);" ) but not work

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_name

href target iframe , rest of it you need to write your own js script based on your requirements .

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
<a onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 0);" href="#" id="test"> Test </a>
```

Comment: Nothing, not work. I try this: a id="#iframe" href="embed.nowvideo.li/embed.php?v=596a96801573b" onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 0);" rel="nofollow" class="selected">Nowvideo ... but onclick not scroll to top.

Comment: `id="iframe"` not `id="#iframe"` . and use `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`  in the page that you want as `<script> window.scrollTo(0, 0); </script>`

Comment: I try it but not want to work.. I not understand why

Answer (score 0):

Try structuring your page like this: (i.e. placing an anchor tag named top at the top of your page)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- your head tags -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- anchor tag to the top -->
    <a name="top"></a>

    <!-- other html -->
    <a href="#top">Go to top</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

when you click the **Go to top** link it will take you to where the anchor with the name **top** is located.

Answer (score -1):

How about wrapping your  into another

```
  <body>
        <a name="top"></a>

        ...

        <a href="#top"><a href="http://google.com" name="iframe" id="test">Google</a></a>
  </body>
```